# How to get the length of a formula in R?

Tags: r, formula, string-length, variable-length

I am trying to get the length of the following formula:

```
myformula <- ~ (1 | Variable1) + (1|Sex) + Age + Cells + Glucose
```

But for some reason, `R` doesn't recognize the real number of elements (which is 5)

```
str(myformula)
Class 'formula'  language ~(1 | Variable1) + (1 | Sex) + Age + Neutrophils + Monocytes
  ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 

length(myformula)
[1] 2
```

(Note: I have variables like this (1|Variable) because I am working with the Variance Partition package (and categorical variables must be written in that format).

Does anyone know how to get the real length of a formula in `R`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `all.vars` to get the variables in the formula and then apply the `length`

```
length(all.vars(myformula))
[1] 5
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy! I didn't know about `all.vars`. Thanks very much!